# Finding the minimal polynomial from characteristic equation

Tags: matrices, notation, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I am attempting to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix. My characteristic equation turns out to be $x^3 - x$ which factors out to $x(x-1)(x+1)$. Now, I am reading that the minimal polynomial is defined as

The unique polynomial of smallest degree which when evaluated at the matrix A is the zero matrix, and I also read that is it a factor of the characteristic equation. So, it must be $x, x-1,$ or $x+1$. But, I do not understand how to compute $A-1$ nor $A + 1$, because we are adding an integer to a matrix.

Comment: In principle you need to also consider the factors of degree $2$ and $3$. You'll learn soon enough, though, that the minimal polynomial necessarily coincides with the characteristic polynomial in this case.

Comment: @GitGud, you were correct! The minimal polynomials are the characteristic polynomials, how did you figure that they were the same without doing the calculations?

Comment: The minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial share the same roots. What they might not share is algebraic multiplicity. But since the algebraic multiplicity of the roots of the characteristic polynomial is as low as possible, there's no wiggle room: the minimal polynomial must be the characteristic polynomial. This is something that you'll be learning very soon, I suspect.

Comment: The word factor is used in the question is confusing; it would be clearer to say the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial (not equation). The word factor _can_ mean any divisor, but is often associated with _irreducible_ (a.k.a. prime) factors, and the question illustrates this confusion. In fact the minimal polynomial must be divisible by _every_ irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace all numbers in the equation with multiples of the identity matrix. So A+1 is really A+I, and A+2 is A+2I.